# We need to fix [star-trek-enterprise] description

Tags: support, status-completed, tags

I can do it myself, but to be honest I wouldn't know what to write instead of what's already there.

The current description begins with:

> "Star Trek: Enterprise" is the most recent Star Trek live-action show to air on TV

Well, not anymore: the most recent is ST:Discovery.

Comment: I've fixed it. I just took out the offending article.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

[Valorum has fixed this](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12321/we-need-to-fix-star-trek-enterprise-description#comment42603_12321) in [this revision](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/revisions/9482/6) changing the sentence to:

> "Star Trek: Enterprise" is a Star Trek live-action show.

In the future as you note yourself you can always edit the description yourself or even raise in chat if you don't feel like making a full meta post about it. There's always a few people in [The Restaurant at the End of the Universe](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58631/the-restaurant-at-the-end-of-the-universe) more than willing to do a quick change to a tag wiki/excerpt.

Comment: Ok, thx. I hadn't thought about the chat.